# maven API incompatibility error for sh.tak.appbundler:appbundle-maven-plugin:1.2.0

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

when I'm trying to build my project (got different modules) in the last module, I'm getting this error message (Using maven 3.6.3 Java 11, also tried with maven 3.6.0)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal sh.tak.appbundler:appbundle-maven-plugin:1.2.0:bundle (default) on project judocu-clientUI: Execution default of goal sh.tak.appbundler:appbundle-maven-plugin:1.2.0:bundle failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing sh.tak.appbundler:appbundle-maven-plugin:1.2.0
:bundle: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>sh.tak.appbundler:appbundle-maven-plugin:1.2.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/sh/tak/appbundler/appbundle-maven-plugin/1.2.0/appbundle-maven-plugin-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/4.2.3/plexus-archiver-4.2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.3.0/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/3.2.0/plexus-io-3.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.8/xz-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity-tools/2.0/velocity-tools-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-chain/commons-chain/1.1/commons-chain-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1/commons-logging-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.3/servlet-api-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.3.1/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.1/dom4j-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/sslext/sslext/1.2-0/sslext-1.2-0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts-core/1.3.8/struts-core-1.3.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts-taglib/1.3.8/struts-taglib-1.3.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts-tiles/1.3.8/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.6.2/velocity-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.2/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.3.9/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.2.v20150114/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.21/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/SelcukCabuk/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : begin 0, end 3, length 2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The weirdest thing is, the same configuration, the same pom.xml, is build successfully on my colleague's laptop, but in mine, I'm getting this error.

Deleting the .m2 folder and let maven download dependencies again didn't solve anything.

What should I think about this problem? If there is really dependency incompatibility, I think maven should build the project at all. But the problem looks specific to my environment.

Below is plugin configuration

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
                <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
                        <version>RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.myProject.CLTapplication</mainClass>
                    <jrePath>./target/jre-mac/jre</jrePath>
                    <!--<dictionaryFile>Info.plist</dictionaryFile>-->
                    <jvmVersion>1.8+</jvmVersion>
                    <bundleName>judocu</bundleName>
                    <version>${mainVersion}</version>
                    <generateDiskImageFile>true</generateDiskImageFile>
                    <includeApplicationsSymlink>true</includeApplicationsSymlink>
                    <iconFile>./src/main/resources/images/iconImage.icns</iconFile>
                    <workingDirectory>$APP_ROOT/Contents/Java/lib</workingDirectory>
                    <jvmOptions>
                        <option>-Djava.library.path=$APP_ROOT/Contents/Java/lib</option>
                        <option>-Xmx768m</option>
                        <option>-splash:splash.png</option>
                    </jvmOptions>
                    <additionalBundledClasspathResources>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>./../licences</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>lib*</include>
                                <include>client.properties</include>
                                <include>splash.png</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileSet>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>./../licences/conf</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>log4jClt.xml</include>
                                <include>log4j.dtd</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileSet>
                    </additionalBundledClasspathResources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: First which Maven Version do you use? And the usage of "RELEASE" as version should be prevented cause such version does not exist...

Comment: @khmarbaise I forgot to tell, I used version 4.2.0 and 4.2.4, got the same problem. And tried with maven 3.6.3 and 3.6.0

Comment: Can you please remove the dependencies form the appbundle-maven-plugin configuration... and run it...

Comment: I don't know why but removing dependencies worked

Comment: Because you are changing the dependencies of the plugin itself which might be incompatible....